# Is there a method like PHPUnit's at method in Mockery?

Tags: php, phpunit, mockery

I want to implement like [at method](http://www.andrejfarkas.com/2012/07/phpunit-at-method-to-check-method-invocation-at-certain-index) in Mockery.

Comment: Generally, one-sentence questions don't work very well here. If you can supply some context, and what you have tried that hasn't worked, it can often help readers who want to assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ordered` features, [from the doc](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/expectations.html):

> Declares that this method is expected to be called in a specific order
>   in relation to similarly marked methods. The order is dictated by the
>   order in which this modifier is actually used when setting up mocks.

Check [this article](http://jontai.me/blog/2012/04/flexible-mock-objects-with-mockery/) for details and the [github repo](https://github.com/padraic/mockery/blob/master/examples/starship/StarshipTest.php) for example.

Hope this help